# flutter_quill Error : Type 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' not found"

Tags: flutter, quill

I am getting this error.

---

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            5.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_quill-6.3.5/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:779:9: Error: Type 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' not found.
../…/widgets/text_selection.dart:779
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited

---

No matter how much I googled, I couldn't find a similar type of error.
can you help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart';

class FlutterQuillScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterQuillScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FlutterQuillScreen> createState() => _FlutterQuillScreenState();
}

class _FlutterQuillScreenState extends State<FlutterQuillScreen> {
  final _controller = QuillController.basic();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          QuillToolbar.basic(controller: _controller),
          QuillEditor.basic(controller: _controller, readOnly: false)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same error. what I did is, I uninstalled flutter and installed new. Then it worked.

Comment: somehow this works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still encounter this.

I also encountered this error. It turns out that I had an old `flutter_quill` version installed because other packages needed to match a specific version. So try checking your `pubspec.yaml` if flutter installed an old version.